# jQuery: clear recursive setTimeout when element is removed

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, recursion

I am attempting to retrieve info from the server through recursive $.ajax() calls, but want to shut those calls off when the element they are bound to is removed.

```
function check_for_update($element) {

    // this is where I need your help fellas:
    $does_this_element_currently_reside_in_the_dom = ????? ; 

    if ($does_this_element_currently_reside_in_the_dom) {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        setTimeout(function() { 
            check_for_update($element) 
        }, 1000);
    } 
}
$ele = $('<div id="element1"></div>');

// start recursion
check_for_update($ele);
```

Removing the element from the DOM should stop the recursion:

```
$ele.remove();
```

Since the element can be removed in a variety of ways, it would be cumbersome to write callbacks for each scenario.  (ie: it can be removed, its parent can be removed, its parent's parent can be removed....).

Thanks!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+does+element+exist+in+dom

Comment: This does not work in this context.

I've tried ($ele.length > 0), this does not work. The element $ele is passed to the function check_for_update() as a jQuery object, thus ($ele.length > 0) will always return true within the scope of the function.

Comment: Why is the variable passed? Why not just select it each time?

Comment: The element is not loaded on page load, it is created by another event, and it can be one of numerous elements and can be removed any number of ways. In this instance, it's a list of clients, each of which has their own set of notes. This recursion is looking for new notes. Thank you, after this chat, I have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! You're a bunch of gents!

Here's my solution that resides within the recursive function:

```
function check_for_update($element) {

    // check for the check_for_update_id attribute
    if ($element.attr('check_for_update_id') === undefined) {
        // set the attribute if it's currently undefined
        d = new Date();
        check_for_update_id = String(d.getTime()) + String(d.getMilliseconds());
        $element.attr('check_for_update_id', check_for_update_id);
        }
    // create $element_new using the check_for_update_id attribute
    $element_new = $(  '[check_for_update_id=' + 
                        $element.attr('check_for_update_id') +
                       ']');

    // if $element has been removed from the DOM,
    // $element_new will not have a 'check_for_update_id' attribute
    if ($element_new.attr('check_for_update_id') !== undefined) {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        setTimeout(function() { 
            check_for_update($element_new);
        }, 1000);
    } 
}
```

The first time the element is passed to the function, the attribute 'check_for_update_id' will be undefined in $element. If it is currently undefined, 'check_for_update_id' is set, and all subsequent setTimeout() calls to the check_for_update() function, $element will now have this 'check_for_update_id' value associated with it. To avoid collision, I've set 'check_for_update_id' to the seconds + milliseconds when this function is called (which is a bit overkill for my purposes, but better safe than sorry).

Then $element_new is created within the function using the 'check_for_update_id' attribute as the selector:

```
$element_new = $(  '[check_for_update_id=' + 
                    $element.attr('check_for_update_id' + 
                   ']');
```

If $element has been removed between setTimeout() iterations, the 'check_for_update_id' attribute will be undefined for $element_new , and setTimeout() will not be called again.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the element exist inside setTimeout and clear the timer. See below,

```
function check_for_update($element) {

    var timer; //added
    // this is where I need your help fellas:
    $does_this_element_currently_reside_in_the_dom = ????? ; 

    if ($does_this_element_currently_reside_in_the_dom) {
        $.ajax({ ... });
        //v-- Added timer var
        timer = setTimeout(function() { 
            if ($('#element1').length) clearTimeout(timer); //Added
            check_for_update($element) 
        }, 1000);
    } 
}
$ele = $('<div id="element1"></div>');

// start recursion
check_for_update($ele);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking for a solution that resides within the scope of the function so as not to pollute the global space. Also, your solution uses the element id as the selector on line ($('#element1').length, not the jQuery object passed to the function. That said, this conversation has been extremely helpful talking through the problem.

Comment: @clutterjoe At what point are you removing the `$ele`. The jQuery object `$ele` is created with the div element, but that jQuery object is never updated when you remove the element. See this simple DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/b9waE/. Also for the variable, you can keep it inside the function.

Comment: The function is attempting to load the latest notes from the server. $element refers to the wrapper in which the notes reside. If $element is removed (and it can be removed by closing the notes pane, or its parent) the recursion kept going. This became cumbersome when other sets of notes were being polled as well. This discussion definitely helped me get my head around the issue, so thanks!